# Numerical evaluation of the Schläfli integral

Tags: integration, special-functions, bessel-functions, numerical-calculus

I'm trying to numerically evaluate
$$
S_{\nu}(z) = \int_0^\infty \exp\bigl(-\nu t - z \sinh(t)\bigr) \mathrm{d}t
$$
where $\nu, z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\Re(z) > 0$. This integral is a part of the [Schläfli representation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchlaeflisFormula.html) of the Bessel function $J_\nu(z)$.

So I separate the real part and the imaginary part and I do the change of variables $t = \dfrac{u}{1-u}$. The problem is that after trying with two numerical integration calculators, the result is `NaN` for both the real part and the imaginary part.

For the real part of the integrand, using a computer algebra system, I get, letting $z = x+iy$ and $\nu = a+ib$,:
$$
\exp\bigl(-x \sinh(t)-at\bigr) \cos\bigl(-y\sinh(t)-bt\bigr).
$$
Then I replace $t$ with $\dfrac{u}{1-u}$ and I multiply by $\dfrac{1}{{(1-u)}^2}$ and I evaluate the integral from $0$ to $1$.

Why does it fail? Am I doing something bad or wrong ?

Here is the integrand in $u$:
$$
\exp\left(-x\sinh\bigl(u/(1-u)\bigr)-au/(1-u)\right) \cos\left(-y\sinh\bigl(u/(1-u)\bigr)-bu/(1-u)\right) / {(1-u)}^2
$$

Comment: Could you show your expression for the integral after the $u$-substitution please?

Comment: @Jam Done. But I've just replaced, I don't simplify anything.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong in principle with your method, but it could be that your numerical integration systems are failing to integrate at the pole at $u=1$. You could try setting $u$ to a sequence approaching $1$ and assess whether it appears to be approaching the desired values.

Comment: With MATHEMATICA it works fine.

Comment: @Jam You're right, with $0.999$ it works.

Comment: @Cesareo Not surprising. But I'm doing a Haskell library.

Comment: This is the [Anger Weber $A_v(z)$ function](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/AngerWeberA/). It is in the [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/11.10)