# Anger-Weber function for an integer value of the order

Tags: special-functions, bessel-functions, numerical-calculus

The Anger-Weber function is defined by
$$
A_{\nu}(z) = \int_0^\infty \exp\bigl(-\nu t - z \sinh(t)\bigr) \mathrm{d}t
$$
where $\nu, z \in \mathbb{C}$ with $\Re(z) > 0$.

I am [not able to numerically evaluate this integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4772927/38217).

But there is an elementary relation involving this function, the Bessel function of the first kind $J$, and the Anger function $\mathbf{J}$. I'm able to numerically evaluate $J$ and $\mathbf{J}$, and thanks to this elementary relation, I can get $A_\nu(z)$ *except when $\nu$ is an integer* (because there's a division by $\sin(\nu\pi)$).

Therefore I'm looking for a way to evaluate $A_\nu(z)$ for the special case when $\nu$ is an integer.

#### References

- [Wolfram](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/AngerWeberA/)
- [DLMF](https://dlmf.nist.gov/11.10)

Comment: Did you try taking a limit? As $v\to\Bbb Z$  $(J_v(z)-\boldsymbol J_v(z))\csc(\pi v)\to0\infty$ which is indeterminate and the $0$ and $\infty$ should “cancel” each other out to give an answer